# legend should show each disaster type only once, but shows multiple times

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help to fix my legend. In one visualisation it worked well, but here each type has multiple colors.[I want to see each disaster type only once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJty9.png)
My code:

```
continent_filter = widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=['Africa', 'Americas', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
    value=[pivot_df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()[0]],
    description='Continent',
    disabled=False
)
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'purple', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'lime', 'pink', 'teal', 'brown', 'gray', 'olive', 'navy']

def update_plot(continent):
    ax = pivot_df[continent].plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, color= colors, figsize=(15, 6))
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Number of Events')
    plt.title('Number of Events by Year, Continent, and Disaster Type')
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
    xtick_labels = [label.get_text().split('-')[0] for label in ax.get_xticklabels()]
    ax.set_xticklabels(xtick_labels)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.show()

widgets.interact(update_plot, continent=continent_filter)
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Tried to use colormap and also a list of colors, same result.
Expecting to see the same like here, each disaster type only once.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xaq2c.png)

Comment: Pls provide some sample data of `pivot_df` in text form, even one continent with 2-3 years and 2-3 events would suffice. The issue appears to be in the way you are creating the `pivot_df`

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was with the pivot_df, indeed. I could solve it. Thanks a lot for your help.